# Express js not returning full error on status code 500 but does with code 200

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have an express js project that has a try catch, when i respond with status code 500 i get no error detail returned.

Below you can see that when i return status code 200 i get a full response with the error and in this case 'Invalid time value'.
[image]

[image]

But when i change to status code 500 i get hardly any information, how do i send status code 500 but still get full error information?

[image]
[image]